# JQuery Mobile Image Size (inside div)

Tags: jquery, image, mobile

I'm using the stock 2 column JQuery mobile layout 'ui-grid-a'.

Why does this work

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a"> <!-- ui-grid-a is a preset 2 column layout in JQuery Mobile -->
        <div class="ui-block-a"><!-- ui-block-a is a preset block in JQuery Mobile, it denotes the left column -->
            <img src="images/a.jpg" style="width:100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><!-- Right column -->
            <p>Right column...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Yet this doesn't...

```
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.full-image
{
    width:100%;
}
</style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a"> <!-- ui-grid-a is a preset 2 column layout in JQuery Mobile -->
        <div class="ui-block-a"><!-- ui-block-a is a preset block in JQuery Mobile, it denotes the left column -->
            <img src="images/a.jpg" class="full-image" />
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><!-- Right column -->
            <p>Right column...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, using css on the img directly (img { width: 100% }) doesn't work either.

Comment: have you tried it with !important ? It may be overwritten..